# How to get the original map marker icon, in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When creating custom map marker icons, how can I programmatically get the original marker icon?

There's a variety of SO threads on customizing map markers, and I've successfully done so, however all of the solutions posted involve importing new PNG icons.

Using the same method (i.e. BitmapDescriptorFactory), how can you use the original default marker icon and do something to it (e.g. add text floating above it).

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code!

```
new MarkerOptions()
        .position(YOUR_latLng)
        .title(YOUR_TITLE)
        .snippet("snippet")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)) //You can select different color! 
    );
```

Comment: This works if you just want to modify existing properties of map markers. However if you want to add new elements (e.g. text floating above the default map marker), then you are forced to re-generate the map marker. When re-generating the map marker, how can we start with the original map marker icon, without resorting to finding the icon in Google Images and importing it into Android Studio? Now I see a SO thread referencing this, but no answer to the original question: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605219/default-marker-for-android-google-mapview#comment3785532_3605262

Comment: Im pretty sure this should be marked as accept. It shows how to get the default marker and also how to put more details such as a title or an snippet